# Set IconButton color in Theme without overriding disabled color

Tags: flutter, material3

With the introduction of material3, my IconButtons have a certain opacity to it, while they were completely white in material2. I want to override it to make them again completely white in material3. I tried this:

```
iconButtonTheme: IconButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
  )
),
```

However, this permanently sets the color to white which means, when a button is disabled it is still white. It should have an opacity to it to indicate it is disabled.

How can I set the IconButton color in my theme without overriding the disabled color?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it like this?

```js
iconButtonTheme: IconButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
          return Colors.grey;
        }
        return Colors.white;
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```